# Revised macro behaving strangely, both working and not working

Tags: excel, vba

The new version of a macro I use (tring to make it faster), runs in a new (pristine) workbook but in

my "working" workbook (which has other macros) the new macro runs only if I run the `original` macro

ona field then run the new macro after it and then it works on any fields.

Or the new macro works in the "Working" workbook if I close then open the WB then run the new macro.

This is the only macro that behaves this way.

Can someone see is this a problem with the new macro or is there a hidden problem or conflict in my "working" workbook

Thanks

```
Sub RemoveCharList()
fRemoveCharList Array("field2", "field4", "field5", "field7"), Array("]", "&", "%")
End Sub
```

New Macro

```
Sub fRemoveCharList(ColArray As Variant, char As Variant)
Dim j As Long, Heading As Variant, headingFound As Range
For Each Heading In ColArray
Set headingFound = Range("1:1").Find(What:=Heading)
If Not headingFound Is Nothing Then
    With Range(headingFound, Cells(Rows.Count, headingFound.Column).End(xlUp))
        For j = LBound(char) To UBound(char)
            .Replace char(j), vbNullString
         Next
      End With
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Original Macro

```
Sub fRemoveCharList(ColArray As Variant, char As Variant)

Dim x As Variant
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim Heading As Variant
Dim headingFound As Range
Dim lngColIndex As Long

For Each Heading In ColArray
    On Error Resume Next
    Set headingFound = Range("1:1").Find(What:=Heading, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0: On Error GoTo -1
    If Not headingFound Is Nothing Then lngColIndex = headingFound.Column
    'If headingFound.Column Then lngColIndex = headingFound.Column


  LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngColIndex).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 1 To LR
      With Cells(i, lngColIndex)
          x = .Value
          For j = LBound(char) To UBound(char)
              x = Replace(x, char(j), vbNullString)
          Next
          .Value = x
       End With
    Next i
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always a good idea to tell Range to which sheet it belongs to, else it will take ActiveSheet range.

There is no need for `for loop` ( For i = 1 To LR) which goes through each cell and checks for special characters instead the code can search for special characters in entire range( first cell to bottom) and use a replace method.

I hope these changes makes the code work faster.

```
Sub fRemoveCharList(ColArray As Variant, char As Variant)


    Dim LR As Long, j As Long
    Dim Heading As Variant
    Dim headingFound As Range, rng As Range


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each Heading In ColArray
            Set headingFound = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:=Heading, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)

            If Not headingFound Is Nothing Then

                LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, headingFound.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rng = .Range(headingFound, .Cells(LR, headingFound.Column))

                For j = LBound(char) To UBound(char)
                    rng.Replace char(j), vbNullString
                Next

            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Santosh, thank you. your answers always have a palpable kindness to them.